# Wind is blowing against a plane, what direction should the plane head towards to end up at the airport?

Tags: kinematics

A plane is flying with a speed of 550km/h with respect to the air hoping to land at an airport due south. There is a strong wind blowing at 68km/h against the plane at 30 degrees [N of W]. What direction should the plane head towards in order to land at the airport?

I've just started teaching myself 2D kinematics. I'm having trouble with this question because I can't figure out what values are given and what values I need. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be solved using vectors. The question has given you the the velocity and direction of the wind. Let this be $\vec {V_w}$. The question also mentions the velocity of the plane w.r.t. the wind. This will be ${\vec {V_p}}-{\vec {V_w}}$. Now draw a diagram representing these two and the airport. Take components of these and you should get the answer.